# How to resize image to fit in graphic view

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have code that displays an image with its name on `listWidget`. In that case the image won't fit in the graphics view. I tested some of resizing methods. But the images won't resize.

How can I resize images to fit in? Please take a look my code.

```
directory.setNameFilters({"*.png", "*.jpg"});

for(const QFileInfo & finfo: directory.entryInfoList()){
    auto imageObject = new QImage();
    imageObject->load(finfo.absoluteFilePath());

    auto image = QPixmap::fromImage(*imageObject);

    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);

    scene->addPixmap(image);
    //scene->setSceneRect(image.rect());
    QGraphicsView *graphicsView = new QGraphicsView(scene);
    graphicsView->fitInView(scene->sceneRect(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

    auto item = new QListWidgetItem("", ui->listWidget_main);
    auto    widget = new QWidget;
    auto    label = new QLabel(finfo.fileName());
    auto    vb = new QVBoxLayout;

    vb->addWidget(label);
    vb->addWidget(graphicsView);

    widget->setLayout(vb);
    widget->setMinimumSize(340,340);
    ui->listWidget_main->setItemWidget(item,widget);
}
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not very helpful problem description...

Comment: what is the `scene->sceneRect()` value? What kind of magic it should provide desired size?

Comment: That's why I am asking. How can I resize??

Comment: Can you show what output screen you get ? are the graphics _overlapping_?

Comment: @MohammadKanan  Here is the output what is going on . This output contains video player and text edit but u can see images clearly.Here is the link  https://ibb.co/gEMYEJ

Comment: I see you got solution with `QLabel`, though you still can do with `QGraphicsView`, the thing is your code does not produce the output you shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use QLabel instead of QGraphicsView

```
directory.setNameFilters({"*.png", "*.jpg"});

    for(const QFileInfo & finfo: directory.entryInfoList()){

        QPixmap image(finfo.absoluteFilePath());
        auto imageLabel = new QLabel();
        imageLabel->setMinimumSize(320,320);
        imageLabel->setScaledContents(true);
        imageLabel->setPixmap(image);



        auto    item = new QListWidgetItem("",listWidget_main);
        auto    widget = new QWidget;
        auto    label = new QLabel(finfo.fileName());
        auto    vb = new QVBoxLayout;

        vb->addWidget(label);
        vb->addWidget(imageLabel);

        widget->setLayout(vb);
        widget->setMinimumSize(340,340);
        listWidget_main->setItemWidget(item,widget);
}
```